# Normal Mapping and Per Vertex Normal

Tags: opengl-es, 3d

I am fairly new to opengl programming, and I have always struggle getting the vertex normal calculations for my 3d shapes, it always depends on how I draw and calculate the triangles, so I wonder if I can avoid the normal calculations by using normal mapping?

Any help and/or reference material will be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot avoid the normal calculations if using normal mapping. Actually you've to calculate two additional vectors for each vertex, tangent and binormal, to make normal mapping work.

However I don't see your problem. Calculating a normal is about the easiest thing to do. Pseudocode for per face and per vertex normal calculation:

```
foreach face in model.faces:
    face.normal = crossproduct(
                       model.vertices[face.vertindex[1]].pos - model.vertices[face.vertindex[0]].pos, 
                       model.vertices[face.vertindex[2]].pos - model.vertices[face.vertindex[0]].pos )
    foreach v in face.vertindex:
        model.vertices[v].in_faces.append(face)

foreach vertex in model.vertices:
    vertex.normal = (0,0,0)
    for face in vertex.in_faces:
        vertex.normal += face.normal
    vertex.normal = vertex.normal / length(vertex.normal)

crossproduct(v0, v1):
    return (
        v0.y * v1.z - v0.z * v1.y,
        v0.z * v1.x - v0.x * v1.z,
        v0.x * v1.y - v0.y * v1.x,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Normal mapping allows to specify per-pixel normals to use in pixel shader. But these per-pixel normals usually only perturbing interpolated normals, so you need to calculate them anyway. You can get rid of vertex normals only if they would be backed up into textures.

Comment: Thanks! can you elaborate a bit this bit "You can get rid of vertex normals only if they would be backed up into textures"

Comment: Ok, I'll try... Usually complex materials are composed of colored texture and normal map (and maybe others, like specular map.) These maps created in tangent-space - this means they're in local surface coordinates, without knowledge of model shape. Normals from these maps are only added to interpolated normals, perturbing them. If you want them to be in model-space, they should include model normals and have to unique for every model point.

Comment: @Ricardo, @alxx: Baking the normals into a texture is even more complicated than simple per vertex normal calculation.

Comment: So it's better to investigate what's wrong with your normal's calculation, because it's much harder to avoid them. @datenwolf: Written same thing in same time :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can: using an object-space normal map.

Tangential space has strong benefits, but it will require you to have either normal+tangent pair or a quaternion.